# Univocity - return wrapped record with error context

Tags: java, univocity

Say I am parsing a CSV employee file. I have a pojo called Employee and i'm using univocity routines and an iterator.

```
Iterator<Employee> iterator = routines.iterate(Employee.class, ...)
```

When an error occurs when parsing a row, I don't want to use the setProcessorErrorHandler() callback. Instead I want to return a generic "Record" or "Item" wrapper which wraps Employee and any error context info if applicable. A bit like how the [JTinyCsvParser](https://github.com/bytefish/JTinyCsvParser) library's [CsvMappingResult](https://github.com/bytefish/JTinyCsvParser/blob/master/JTinyCsvParser/src/main/java/de/bytefish/jtinycsvparser/mapping/CsvMappingResult.java) object behaves.

Is there an easy way of doing this short of catching for example com.univocity.parsers.common.DataProcessingException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but you still need to use the `RetryableErrorHandler` and from it you must call `keepRecord()` to prevent the record from being discarded. This way you will get your problematic `Employee` instance with the information that could be parsed.

Comment: Although it still seems they are two separate pipelines. There's no way to get the error context after keepingrecord() from that handler back into the main iterator, unless you log or keep the error records elsewhere and complete parsing of the whole file. If you have error info early on, you can choose to quit the processing eagerly.

Comment: You can use the `Context` object provided by the error handler to execute `context.stop()` and stop parsing immediately.

Comment: Agreed that will work. It seems I have to keep a (ThreadLocal?) flag/counter in the thread because an Iterator doesn't know an error has occurred still.

Comment: The iterator has a context object too. Use IterableResult<Employee> iterator = routines.iterate(..)